# Is there a reason to assume that the parameter in a statistical model is a realization of a random variable?

Tags: regression, conditional-probability, model

> Why is it common to write a statistical model as a family of
>   conditional distributions - conditioned on a realization of a
>   particular parameter-value - when the definition of a statistical model
>   is a family of distributions $P_{\theta } $ on some space
>   $\mathcal{S}$ [See e.g. the article Statistical model on Wikipedia.],
>   with no consideration on them being conditional distributions?

For example consider the family of random variables $Y_{(\beta_0,\beta_1 )}: \ (\Omega, P) \to \mathcal{S}$

$$Y_{(\beta_0,\beta_1 )}(\omega) := \beta_0 + \beta_1X(\omega) + \epsilon(\omega)$$

then

$$\mu_{(\beta_0,\beta_1)}  := P \circ Y_{(\beta_0,\beta_1 )}$$

would be a statistical model under the definition on Wikipedia as refered to above.

Now under some extra conditions on the random variables $X $ and $\epsilon$ we would have that for each parameter $(\beta_0, \beta_1)$, the conditional distribution of $Y_{(\beta_0,\beta_1 )}(\omega)$ given $X = x$ is the normal distribution with mean $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x $ and variance $\sigma ^2$. This sounds like a simple linear regression - as introduced in many places.

But many books also defines the simple linear regression model as that $Y $ conditioned on that $X = x$ and $\beta = (\beta_0, \beta_1) $ follows a normal distribution with mean $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x $ and variance $\sigma ^2$. **That is they assumes that also the parameter $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$ is a realization of a random variable.** Why is this so?

> Generally for a statistical model: what would the reason to assume the
>   additional structure that the parameter is a realization of a random
>   variable so that we may consider $$\mu_\theta  := P(Y | \Theta =
>  \theta)$$ instead of $$\mu_\theta  := P_\theta \circ Y$$ $$?$$

Comment: Research "Bayesian statistics:" insisting on an assumption of a probability distribution on parameters characterizes this philosophy.